How to copy Sharepoint Lists and Libraries from one site to another site
How can I copy Sharepoint list and library from the one site to another, for example:
Copy Lists and Libraries from https://myCompany/sites/mySite1 to https://myCompany/sites/mySite2.
I just want the structure/settings/columns without the data.

On the target SharePoint Online site (mySite2):

Open Site Contents
Click on New > List > Create a list > From existing list
Select an existing list
Browser the source list from the source SharePoint site (mySite1)
Click on Next, enter a new name and description





To copy SharePoint lists and libraries from one site to another without transferring the data, you can save the list as a template and then create a new list from that template in the target site. Here’s how you can do it:

Save the List as a Template:

Go to your source site, e.g., https://myCompany/sites/mySite1

Navigate to the list you want to copy.

Click on the settings (gear icon) and select "List settings."

Under the "Permissions and Management" section, click on "Save list as template."

Fill in the required fields and make sure to check the option to
include content if needed (but in your case, leave it unchecked).

Save the template.



Create a New List from the Template:

Go to your target site, e.g., https://myCompany/sites/mySite2
Click on "Site contents." Select "New" and then "List."
Choose "From your organization" to find your saved template.
Select the template you created and follow the prompts to create the new list.



